# Windows File Explorer Address line is BLACK and the path is compressed

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10-v1803

My windows file explorer is acting strange... I have windows 10 pro creators edition and the file explorer, at times, sporadically, causes issues with the path displaying BLACK and the path, compressed so small that you cannot read the path names... there's no code here but this is consistent with File Explorer and I cannot do anything to fix it save for restarting my computer.  Restarting File Explorer doesn't help either.

[image: File Explorer with BLACK covering PATH]

This even occurs in the File Save As...

[image: File Explorer SAVE AS... dialog affected too!]

This is file explorer when not in focus when I was taking a screen shot of the SAVE AS... dialog

[image: File Explorer when not in Focus during screen cap of Save As...]

Finally, another shot of File Explorer when I moved my mouse rapidly left and right over the PATH but didn't click any buttons.

[image: File Explorer when moving mouse left and right rapidly no mouse clicks]

Also, when I right click, this is what happens... part of the sub menu starts disappearing.  NOTE: The BLUE "X" is OPEN PDF... believe it or not.

WINDOWS 10 PRO - v1803 Build: 17134.472

[image: File Explorer Right-Click menu starts disappearing...]

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before???  There's got to be a solution, permanently!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not be having the issue anymore, but I found a solution that can hopefully help others.

[Here is where I found it](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-explorer-navigation-pane-suddenly-showing/4f40804d-5f63-40c9-b4fc-2d31318fdb99).

1. Open an elevated Command Prompt (run Command Prompt as an Administrator).
2. Enter the following command. There will be a visible progress bar and a message that tells you it has completed. This should take only a few minutes (~2-3).

   `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth`
3. Once the previous action has completed, run the next command. This one will show a similar progress bar and completion message, and takes roughly another minute or two.

   `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

---

This was able to fix it for me, at least. I'm not sure what the cause was, but in the link I posted, here is the explanation. I hope this helps anyone who may stumble upon this post.

> Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) is a new command line tool that you can use to service a Windows image or prepare a Windows PE image. The DISM tool replaces the Package Manager (pkgmgr.exe), PEimg, and Intlcfg tools. DISM consolidates the functionality found in those three tools, as well as delivers new functionality to improve the experience of offline servicing.

Comment: `dism` repair is the new `sfc /scannow` it seems, the magic cure-all for Windows ailments. Here is some helpful links related to the command: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image